# node.js web service for mobile apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, service, web

I would like to create a web service for a mobile app chained to a mongodb where I would store some user specific data. Since I'm new to node and I just finished reading the Node.js in Action book by Mike Cantelon & Tj Holowaychuk I am now trying to think which framework should I use in order to create the server. I think it would be either connect or express but I am not sure. I saw that express is used mostly for creating web apps rather than web servers. What do you guys recommend me? In addition some tutorials to get me started in this direction would be most welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question?  "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use express, It is common in developping node.js application and you will find a lot of tutorials that will help you. Also express provide you with RESTful API which will help you a lot to access your data from mobile

and these are some links to help you to start with express

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/introduction-to-express/

http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/03/a-sample-app-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb-part-1/

http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-create-rest-api

Answer (score 2):

Express uses Connect, and is fine for most applications.  It will certainly be fine for, "a web service for a mobile app chained to a mongodb where I would store some user specific data."

It isn't possible to give a more specific recommendation, as you provided no specific details in your question.

> I saw that express is used mostly for creating web apps rather than web servers.

This doesn't make much sense really.  Node.js provides the server `http.Server` and you create the application layer behind it.  Express is often used to provide common functionality such as routing and a Connect stack of modules for handling requests.